# Ctrl+C kills PuTTY

Tags: linux, putty

I am trying to help a co-worker, where upon logging onto our RHEL server via PuTTY, if they hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (or type `exit`), it kills the session.

I checked their default login shell is KSH, same as mine.

I've done some reading, https://groups.google.com/d/topic/...ssh/difmwuOhbsk and am trying to deduce if their ksh is not spawning correctly (so when ksh is finished, the session is finished also, and PuTTY exits).

Not sure how to proceed from here... as far as I can tell the last three entries from today looks good(?)

**Question:** Am I supposed to look for a profile setting on RHEL or PuTTY? and what is it?

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
a_user_name   18050     1  0 Apr04 ?        00:00:00 -ksh
a_user_name   18311 18050  0 Apr04 ?        00:00:10 find / -name foo*
a_user_name   18335     1  0 Apr04 ?        00:00:00 -ksh
a_user_name   18428 18335  0 Apr04 ?        00:00:09 find / -name fooX*
a_user_name   18555     1  0 Apr04 ?        00:00:00 -ksh
a_user_name   18685 18555  0 Apr04 ?        00:00:09 find / -name foo*
a_user_name   23930 23923  0 08:41 ?        00:00:00 sshd: a_user_name@pts/1
a_user_name   23931 23930  0 08:41 pts/1    00:00:00 -ksh
a_user_name   28503 23931  0 10:19 pts/1    00:00:00 ps -fu a_user_name
```

Comment: Does ctrl+d do the same thing?

Comment: Does using Bash instead exhibit the same issue?